# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$ then $D_f \subset D_g$. Is this true?

Tags: calculus

Let the domain of $g(x)$ be $D_g$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$

I think that the domain of $f(x)$ is a subset of domain of $g(x)$ because

`1.` $f(x)$ is not defined where $g(x)=0$.

`2.` f(x) is not defined at those points where  $g(x)$ is not defined.

**My brother said that `2.` is wrong but he wasn't having any solid reason.
Kindly make me understand how `2.` is wrong( not by giving an counter example because I already have one ).**

I was doing trigonomentry, in that I found that $$\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$ $x\ne n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer.

Then I thought of writing $\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$, from here I concluded that $\cot(x)$ is not defined when $\tan(x)=0$ and also where $\tan(x)$ is not defined **but this is wrong**.

**I need to understand that how $f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$ is defined at those points where g(x) is not defined.**

I know I'm making a little mistake but I don't understand that, please don't give the counterexample **kindly make me understand where and how I'm making the mistake**.

Comment: Your example is misleading, since the definition of $\cot$ is not the inverse of $\tan$. If you define $f(x)$ as the inverse of $g(x)$, it cannot be defined when $g(x)$ is not, by definition...

Comment: Consider the case $g(x) = 1/x$.  Then $f(x)=x$ is defined at $x=0$, while $g(x)$ is not.  Part of the problem here is having a rigorous notion of "domain".

Comment: @Slade Note that if $f$ is defined as $1 / g$, $f(0)$ is *not* defined.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi This is all an issue of definitions.  $x = (1/x)^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}(x)$, for example, but it's perfectly well defined at $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g$ has domain $D_g$ and $f$ is defined by $f = 1/g$, then $f$ has maximal domain--what we normally take to be the domain of the function--of $$D_f = D_g \cap \{ x \ | \ g(x) \neq 0 \} \subset D_g$$

In that sense as functions, $\tan \neq 1/\cot$. There are points in the domain of $\tan$ for which $\cot$ is not defined, e.g., $0 \in D_{\tan}$ but $0 \not\in D_{\cot}$.

What is true however is that for all $x \in D_{\tan} \cap D_{\cot}$, $\tan x = 1/\cot x$.

---

*Added:* Here's one definition of a function (there are other more formal definitions but this version contains the essential idea for your question):

> $f : D \to C$ is a rule that associates to each $d \in D$, the domain, a member of $C$, the codomain. We write $f(d)$ for that member of $C$.

Hence the two essential components of a function $f$ are the domain of $f$ and the 'rule' for the value of each value of the domain when acted on by $f$.
Thus

$$f_1 : [0,1] \to \mathbb R \quad \text{ with } f(x) = \sin(100x)$$

is a different function from

$$f_2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \quad \text{ with } f(x) = \sin(100x)$$

because the domains are different. (Even though other things are the same, such as the codomain and the range, and that for every point $p$ in the intersection of the domains the functions agree, $f_1(p) = f_2(p)$).

The function $\tan$ has domain $D_{\tan} = \{ x \in \mathbb R \ | \  x \neq \pi/2 + k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z \}$. I.e., $\tan : D_{\tan} \to \mathbb R$. Similarly the function $\cot$ has domain $D_{\cot} = \{ x \in \mathbb R \ | \  x \neq  k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z \}$.

The function $TAN2$ defined by $TAN2 = 1/\cot$ has domain

$$D_{TAN2} = D_{\cot} \cap \{ x \in \mathbb R\ | \cot(x) \neq 0 \} \hspace{30 mm} \\ = D_{\cot} \cap \{ x \in \mathbb R  \ | \  x \neq \pi/2 + k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z \} \\ 
= \{ x \in \mathbb R  \ | \  x \neq  k\pi/2, k \in \mathbb Z \} \hspace{ 19 mm} $$

Are the functions $TAN2$ and ordinary $\tan$ equal? No! They cannot be because they have different domains. $D_{TAN2}$ is a strict subset of $D_{\tan}$.

That is, as functions

$$TAN2 = \frac{1}{\cot} \neq \tan$$

However at every point in the intersection of their domains, $D_{\tan} \cap D_{TAN2} = D_{TAN2}$, the rules for $TAN2$ and $\tan$ agree, i.e.,

$$\tan x = \frac{1}{\cot x}, \quad \text{ for all }  x \in \mathbb R \text{ with }  x \neq  k\pi/2, k \in \mathbb Z $$

Thus when we write

$$\tan x = \frac{1}{\cot x} \quad \text{ or } \quad \cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}$$

what that means is "for every $x$ in the intersection of the domains of $\tan$ and $\cot$, those relations are true".

Comment: Sir are you saying that it is not possible to find the domain of $tan$  when we write take $tan$ as inverse of $cot$. In my book it is clearly writen that $cot$ is inverse of $tan$. $cot(x)=\frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}=\frac{1}{tan(x)}$ this is true. Then where is the mistake.

Comment: @Singh Added detail above which I hope answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional conditions, the statement implicitly means the domains are the same and the equality holds at each point of the common domain.